# SwiftUI - open sheet from various views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-sheet

So I have a sheet like this

```
      .sheet(item: $logMyPractice, content: { item in
          AssesmentRecorderView(
            assessment: DrillModel(
              questions: [
                .init(prompt: "Question 1", resultValue: .integer),
              ]
            ),
            completion: { date, answers in
              print("response", date, answers)
              // custom logic, save in the db
            })
          .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.85), .large ])
        }
```

What is happening is that I need to open that sheet from a different views.
I could copy/paste it to the separate views but it's not following a `DRY` concept.

I could create an `ObservableObject` in the main view that holds information about the sheet and attach it as a `environmentObject`, but I wonder if there's a better approach?

Comment: You could try notifications, I do something similar with an alert for errors

Comment: Sorry. Im new with SwiftUI. Can you explain it better please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the power of the [ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier)

You can do something like this

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Button {
                isPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }

        }
        .customSheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { singleString, arrayString in
            print(singleString)
            print(arrayString)
        }
    }
 }
    
    struct CustomSheetViewModifier: ViewModifier {
        
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        
        let completionHandler: ((String, [String]) -> Void)?
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                    Button {
                        completionHandler?("Done", ["Button 1", "Button 2"])
                        isPresented = false
                    } label: {
                        Text("Click me")
                    }
    
                }
        }
    }

extension View {
    func customSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, completionHandler: ((String, [String]) -> Void)?) -> some View {
        modifier(CustomSheetViewModifier(isPresented: isPresented, completionHandler: completionHandler))
    }
}
```

and in your case you will replace the body of the CustomeSheetViewModifier with this

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                AssesmentRecorderView(
                    assessment: DrillModel(
                        questions: [
                            .init(prompt: "Question 1", resultValue: .integer),
                        ]
                    ),
                    completion: { date, answers in
                        completionHandler(date, answers)
                    })
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.85), .large ])
            }
    }
```

assuming that the date is a string and the answers is an array of Strings you of course can replace the completionHandler parameters with whatever you like

Comment: this is more less what I have now. Now Imagine you have a `ContentView` and `DetailView`. Both should have the same `.sheet`. One solution is to copy over and over the same code, so you will have `.customSheet(isPresented: $isPresented)` in both views.

Comment: I wonder if ther's a good approach to add a `.customSheet(isPresented: $isPresented)` to the `MainView` and from `ContentView` open that sheet. Assuming that `ContentView` and `DetailView` are 4th child views of MainView.
One solution is like I've already mentioned, to put an ObservaleObject in the MainView and attach it as an `environmentObject` but I don't know if that's the right way to do it

Comment: I totally  understand what you are trying to do but keep in mind .sheet is a modifier like .frame and .foregroundColor so it's normal to repeat it but whatever you put inside the .sheet modifier closure it should't be repeated so what's why the best practice is to create customView and add it to the .sheet closure but in your case you have the same .sheet with the same customView inside the closure    will be repeated for multiple views so the best practice here is to make viewModifier and instead of writing .sheet and closure you will write  .customSheet() and that's it

Comment: The approach  you are suggesting is the to put something in the environment and ad the sheet to the mainView it will work but you have to make it bindable so it can opens the sheet you will do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731360/get-a-binding-from-an-environment-value-in-swiftui  but i don't like to write the code like this a always try to make each component can be added to any place in my code with minimal modification at possible so  imagine that you want to remove DetailView and add it to another parent than MainView you will have to add .sheet to that parent

Comment: And you that parent will not use that sheet at all and it's there because the DetailView needs it. Now you have two solutions and they both work but you have to choose what fits your code more.