# Problems trying to use .environment with Binding

Tags: swiftui, binding, environment-variables

In attempting to implement [Get a binding from an environment value in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731360/get-a-binding-from-an-environment-value-in-swiftui) I run into difficulty.

I have a little GlobalAlert class that I make an ObservableObject and publish a Binding<Bool> that is intended to trigger the alert being displayed.

I then make a little custom EnvironmentKey for a Binding<Bool> and extend EnvironmentValues to hold it.

In my App I instantiate a GlobalAlert and make it an ObservedObject and inject it anto the View with a .environment modifier.

In my View, I pick up the EnvironmentValue I have created as a Binding<Bool>

A button in the View calls a method (publish) on the static GlobalAlert I created in the App which sets a state (isAlert) intended to display an alert.

No alert is displayed.

Following the breadcrumbs I note that my publish method does indeed set the isAlert state but by the time .alert gets round to testing it it has been reset.... at least I think that's what's going on. I am guessing that GlobalAlert is being re-instantiated in some way but I am unsure wht this would be as its a static variable in my App.

Forcing the Setter to set the state value to true causes the alert to appear so I know my plumbing is working.

Here is the code...

```
import SwiftUI

enum alertTypes {
    case information
    case error
}

class GlobalAlert: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isAlert: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
    var alert: String = ""
    
    func publish(alert: String, type: alertTypes){
        print("gGlobalAlert publish")
        self.alert = alert
        print (isAlert)
        self.isAlert = .constant(true)
        print (isAlert)
    }
}

struct IsAlertKey: EnvironmentKey{
    static let defaultValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isAlert: Binding<Bool> {
        get {
            print("Get")
            return self[IsAlertKey.self]
        }
        set {
            print("Set \(newValue)")
            self[IsAlertKey.self] = newValue
//            self[IsAlertKey.self] = .constant(true)
        }
    }
}

struct TestAlertApp: App {
    @ObservedObject static var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment( \.isAlert, TestAlertApp.gGlobalAlert.isAlert )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.isAlert) var isAlert: Binding<Bool>
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Test") {
                TestAlertApp.gGlobalAlert.publish(alert: "Alert triggered", type: .error)
            }
            .alert("\(TestAlertApp.gGlobalAlert.alert)", isPresented: isAlert){
                Button("OK", role: .cancel ) {
                    TestAlertApp.gGlobalAlert.isAlert = .constant(false)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `static` with `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: Binding is only for SwiftUI views/DynamicProperty conforming structs

Comment: Constant should only be used in previews, it serves no purpose in production code.

Comment: @jnpdx could you please comment with a reason for your assertion?

Comment: Because the `View` doesn't know to update from the `static` context

Comment: @loremipsum could you clarify your assertions, just a statement is not very helpful.

Comment: The comments are just what I said, they are verbatim. The answer below is a correct implementation. You are misusing Binding, constant and ObservedObject. You are likely coming from another programming language and skipping basic tutorials and videos.

Comment: I do indeed come from other programming language backgrounds. I am highly experienced with likely a far broader background than you with 60 years behind me... yes, I am 72. That experience includes managing compiler writing teams. So, if you would be so kind, could you please explain precisely why attempting to bind to a static object is fundamentally unsound ... and more so why it fails silently.

Comment: It is going to be a very long read and my strong area is not in writing very long explanations... It is a compilation of many bits and pieces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to break it down, note that a lot of the "why"s are unknown but here is the logic I have uncovered over the years since SwiftUI was released.

**Part 1**

SwiftUI as a whole uses property wrappers to access a "secret storage" that we can only access via `DynamicProperty`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

When this secret storage determines ( via `Hashable`, `Identifiable` and `Equatable`) that there is a change the `body` it is reloaded and the `View` is updated on the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Notice I said "property wrappers" (documentation verbiage), while `Binding<Bool>` compiles it does not "work", it isn't an undocumented use, you have to use `@Binding` for the reload to happen properly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

I have only seen Apple use this once for `presentationMode` but they have [since deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/presentationmode) this opted for a version that doesn't use `Binding` [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss).

`@Binding` conforms to `DynamicProperty`

> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

Based on this is why I said my first comment, "`Binding` is only for SwiftUI `view`s/`DynamicProperty` conforming `struct`s ".

`ObservableObject` does not meet this criteria, any use of `Binding` inside one of these will be buggy. It can sometimes act like it is working.

**Part 2**

The way `ObservableObject` works is

> ObservableObject synthesizes an objectWillChange publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published properties changes.

> @ObservedObject subscribes to an observable object and invalidates a view whenever the observable object changes.

With `@ObservedObject` being the one that uses `DynamicProperty` not `ObservableObject` or `@Published`

**Part 3**

`@ObservedObject static`

> SwiftUI might create or recreate a view at any time, so it’s important that initializing a view with a given set of inputs always results in the same view. As a result, it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view. Instead, SwiftUI provides the StateObject attribute for this purpose.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

These are Apple's words not mine, and only they can tell you why but I am pretty sure it boils down to the secret storage.

`static` is actually a workaround for `@ObservedObject`s biggest deficiency (Not being able to manage lifecycle).

That is why Apple gave us `StateObject` in iOS 14.

> Use a state object as the single source of truth for a reference type that you store in a view hierarchy. Create a state object in an App, Scene, or View by applying the @StateObject attribute to a property declaration and providing an initial value that conforms to the ObservableObject protocol. Declare state objects as private to prevent setting them from a memberwise initializer, which can conflict with the storage management that SwiftUI provides:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject

As I general rule I say `StateObject` is for initializing and `ObservedObject`/`EnvironmentObject` are for passing around.

**Part 4**

Mixing `environment` and `ObservedObject`

You have hacked a connection by using `Binding<Bool>` but it just doesn't work for all the reasons above. To put something that is inside an `ObservableObject` into the environment you should use `.environmentObject(_:)` to inject and `@EnvironmentObject` to access where you need it.

**Part 5**

`constant` & `Binding` / Second comment

`Binding` is by definition a two-way connection, its value comes from a source of truth.

In your code a `@StateObject` with an

```
@Published var isAlert: Bool = false
```

should be your source of truth. Now per Apple...

> constant(_:)
> Creates a binding with an immutable value.

> Use this method to create a binding to a value that cannot change. This can be useful when using a PreviewProvider to see how a view represents different values.

in a `View` a `Binding` that doesn't change is the same as a `let` property because "it doesn't change" so if you find a reason to have a `.constant` outside of `Preview`s it is a waste of resources because it is more efficient to have a `let`.

I also see using `.constant` outside of previews misleading. It gives the impression that the specific property is using to a source of truth and for app growth that can be a nightmare if you have a ton of dead ends that aren't really talking to a parent. <- Opinion

**Part 6**

Notice how Apple uses value types to handle "state changes"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state

**TLDR**

1. Why does the example you linked work and not your example? Just guessing but...

In the example you are showing the OP is going from `DynamicProperty` `State` to `DynamicProperty` `EnvironmentValues` so it isn't equivalent to what you are doing. Both are `DynamicProperty` values interfacing directly with the secret storage.

Your setup needs all the mechanics for `ObservableObject`s to work too, `Binding` isn't capable of "publishing" and "emiting" so `DynamicProperty` `ObservedObject` can invalidate the `View`.

Lets not forget that `Binding` is a two-way connection not a source of truth it needs the parent to work properly.

To "fix" your code

Replace

```
@Published var isAlert: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
```

With

```
@Published var isAlert: Bool = false
```

(`Binding` doesn't conform to `Hashable`, `Identifiable` or `Equatable` there is no way to know when to publish.) <<— why I think it fails silently.

Then replace

```
@ObservedObject static var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()
```

With

```
@StateObject private var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()
```

(`static` is not within the `View` to access the Secret Storage and `@ObservedObject` is unsafe.) <<—- why static is unsound.

Then replace

```
.environment( \.isAlert, TestAlertApp.gGlobalAlert.isAlert )
```

With

```
.environmentObject(gGlobalAlert)
```

(You are now passing the object itself.)

Then replace all

```
@Environment(\.isAlert) var isAlert: Binding<Bool>
```

With

```
@EnvironmentObject var gGlobalAlert: GlobalAlert
```

Then you can use

```
$gGlobalAlert.isAlert
```

When you need a `Binding`

But I personally would use `NotificationCenter` for this, you are essentially recreating it with an inefficient version.

I could do into another long explanation as to why. But in short `DynamicProperty` updates and `ObservedObject` invalidates, a wrapper that uses `DynamicProperty` directly will always be more efficient.

**PS...**

The more I think about this if you use

```
@StateObject private var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()
```

and

```
.environment( \.isAlert, $gGlobalAlert.isAlert )
```

and keep your current `EnvironmentValues` setup it "might/should" work but I have not tested this, I also think it would be very inefficient lets not forget about the "invalidating" and that we already have `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: Thanks for that I will read it carefully. I definately got the semantics of .constant wrong. I had thought it was syntax to assign a Binding literal value but its not!

Comment: @TS200010 SwiftUI is special, before swift I worked with Java and many many moons ago I got my start with COBOL and Pascal. I settled for Swift/SwiftUI when I went to WWDC in 2019. I’ve lasted here because it changes so much every June.

Comment: I'm still thinking about your reply and some other materials. I can now see where I got led astray (Binding<subject>) is not intended to be used outside of @Binding where it recieves its  DynamicProperty functionality. However, I am not entirely convinced I understand the full implications yet so I continue to ponder. Pascal eh! it was a Coral 66 compiler that I managed... a similar language used by the MoD at the time!

Comment: OK.. Ive got it all except Part 3. @ObservableObject and static. Yes, ObservableObjects are instantiated every time a View is. That was the whole point of making it **static to App**. static is a declaration-modifier that tells the compiler that one copy is shared by all instances (ie it belongs to the type see Swift Lang Ref (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/declarations#Declaration-Modifiers)...

Comment: ... What's more, static variables have global scope and need no instances. It's exactly this behaviour that I leveraged and it works when combined with your suggestions. (So far at least)

Comment: @TS200010 that is an iffy one I admit, I just take Apple's word for it, maybe it is something to ask in a forum in a couple of weeks. `static` is "global scope" as you said  therefore it is outside of the `View` where the Secret Storage's scope is, I would expect undefined behavior especially because apple says using `ObservableObject` to initialize is unsafe.

Comment: @TS200010. have you checked for leaks? usually when using something like `@ObservedObject var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()` you can easily detect memory leaks it would be interesting to see if `@ObservedObject static var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()` leaks as well or if there are performance hits.

Comment: I don't think there is any _secret storage_ beyond any vars that the property wrappers themselves cause to be added ... you can see this in the debugger if you expand the @Observed etc variables. The static variables I create seem to have the same vars as class/struct based instances. Only scanned briefly though.

Comment: Leaks ... no I have not checked.

Comment: Having said all that, I have googled around trying to find any references to the valid (or otherwise) use of static variables like I have done and I come up blank so far - both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an environment variable, you'd probably be better off using a more straightforward approach with view-model and environment object.

Anyhow, the call to the view-model in the `App` class is wrong: it should be a `@StateObject` when it creates the instance; you shouldn't "observe" an object that you create right in the view (don't use `static` objects for this purpose). And setting a binding variable to a `.constant()` value easily breaks the purpose.

My advice: drop the `IsAlertKey` struct and the `EnvironmentValues` extension; instead, change your `App`, view-model and `View` objects with this:

View-model:

```
class GlobalAlert: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isAlert = false
    var alert: String = ""

    // rest of the code...
}
```

App object:

```
struct TestAlertApp: App {
    @StateObject private var gGlobalAlert = GlobalAlert()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(gGlobalAlert)
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalAlert: GlobalAlert

    // It is better to keep the binding variable separated from the
    // GlobalAlert view model variable, to avoid changing the state
    // while the view updates. isAlert is a local variable that selectively
    // changes according to the value of the view model variable, and vice versa.
    // This allows you to present an alert from anywhere in the code (which I believe is the purpose)
    @State private var isAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Test") {
                globalAlert.publish(alert: "Alert triggered", type: .error)
            }
            .alert(globalAlert.alert, isPresented: $isAlert){
                Button("OK", role: .cancel ) {
                    globalAlert.isAlert = false
                }
            }

            .onChange(of: globalAlert.isAlert) { value in
                isAlert = value
            }
            .onChange(of: isAlert) { value in
                globalAlert.isAlert = value
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Be careful, though, alerts are tricky: if another modal like a sheet is being presented, calling the `GlobalAlert` from somewhere in the code will not work - because SwiftUI will try to show an alert on the *back* of the sheet - and all alerts will stop working. Better to use a "GlobalModal" view object, that handles both sheets and alerts, avoiding overlaps.

Comment: that's very helpful, thanks for taking the time to reply. But still I am left wondering why my code did not work... is there an explanation? After all, Apple uses EnvironmentValues to broadcast fundamental state changes like Dark/Light... that affect global behaviour. The alerts that I plan on raising are of the same ilk... I want to be able to raise from anywhere in my code certain situations that need user attention before anything else can continue.

Comment: In your code you are using the `@StateObject` in a wrong way, calling an `@ObservedObject` that is created instead of being observed. You are also setting constants to binding variables, basically losing the ability of the binding to change its value and update the view accordingly. Using `@EnvironmentObject` allows you to "raise certain situations" in your code, you just need some more learning of the [basics, take a look over here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).