# Why does Binding of CoreData NSManagedObject not update onChange in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, state

**Context**

I have a pretty simple `Form` using the `MVVM` architecture. However, I encountered a problem with this implementation. My `DetailView` has a `DummyState` that changes the corresponding attribute of `Entity` `onChange`.

> **Problem:** Once the `DetailView` appears, both `Toggles` are on which is as expected. However, when turning the local `Toggle` off, the other `Toggle` remains on, which is unexpected. However, as soon as I interact with another element (not in `MRE`), the second `Toggle` seems to refresh and turns off.

---

**Code**

```swift
@objc(Entity) public class Entity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var enabled: Bool
}

class FormViewModel: ObservableObject, CustomFormObservable {
    @Published var entity = Entity(context: ...)

    init() { self.entity.enabled = true }

    var isValid: Bool { self.entity.enabled }
}

struct FormView: View {
    @StateObject private var formVM = FormViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        CustomForm(formVM: formVM) {
            DetailView(entity: $formVM.entity)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var entity: Entity
    @State private var localEnabled: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Local Toggle", isOn: $localEnabled)
            .onChange(of: localEnabled) { entity.enabled = $0 }

        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $entity.enabled)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- What causes this behaviour and how can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211411/problems-trying-to-use-environment-with-binding/76213700#76213700

Comment: All CoreData objects should be wrapped with ObservedObject, their value type variables can use Binding

Comment: @loremipsum thanks a lot for your answer and the resource. That makes sense to me, however, I updated my code as well as the `MRE` and encountered another problem. See the current answer and its comments. Do you have any idea what causes this?

Comment: The Entity has the wrong wrapper also your VM is incapable of observing an observable object. It is an extra unnecessary layer.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for your answer. Which entity wrapper to you mean? And how can I simplify the code by eliminating the layer? A small code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Vadian already gave you the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `NSManagedObject` is reference type.

There is a simple rule:

- `@State` and `@Binding` is for value types like structs.
- `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` is for reference types like classes.

And the *dollar-sign reference* is also only for value types.

Fortunately `NSManagedObject` conforms to `ObservableObject`by default.

---

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject private var formVM = FormViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        DetailView(entity: formVM.entity)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var entity: Entity
    @State private var localEnabled: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Local Toggle", isOn: $localEnabled)
            .onChange(of: localEnabled) { entity.enabled = $0 }

        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $entity.enabled)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! This is the implementation I previously had. However, when changing the `ObservedObject` in `DetailView`, the `@Published var entity` in `FormViewModel` does not update. This was the reason why I switched to `Binding`. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I added some additional code to the `MRE`. I also have a computed property `isValid` which is used to check whether the Save button should be intractable. When I said in my previous comment, that the view does not update, I mean that the `Save` button does not get interactable even though the condition is met.

Comment: Rather than the computed property – which is actually supposed to be @Published, too – use `formVM.entity.enabled` in the view. All `NSManaged` properties **do** publish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I do not fully understand your suggestion. The `CustomForm` is generic and takes a `ViewModel` conforming to `CustomFormObservable` which requires the `isValid` property. I do not have access to the specific `entity` property from within `CustomForm` to check whether the 'Save' button should be intractable, that logic must be outsourced.

Comment: This is actually a new question. My answer solves the @Binding problem. As `NSManagedObject` conforms to `ObservableObject` you could implement a Combine Publisher which controls the `isValid` property.

Comment: You're right. I accepted your answer and asked a new question for this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296952/how-to-update-swiftui-view-according-to-computed-property-in-viewmodel-using-mvv