# Why does the `Binding<Bool>` in XUIView does not see the updated value?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Why does the `Binding<Bool>` in `XUIView` does not see the updated value?

I have a `SwiftUI` `XView` which wraps an `XUIView`. In the `XUIView` I have a `Binding<Bool>`, which is initialised with the `@Binding...` of the `XView`. In the `XUIView` I have a `UIButton` with which I toggle the `customFlag` using the "Binding" property in `XUIView`. That propagates nicely into the `SwiftUI` View, as the `Text` updates properly. However, the `UIButton`'s title is not updated properly. The `XUIView._update` method does not "see" the new value.

What am I missing here?

Do I have to assign the `customFlag` in the `updateUIView` method to make that work?

Sample code with some print calls to see what's going on:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UIKitBindingView: View {
    @State private var customFlag: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("customFlag: \(customFlag ? "ON" : "OFF")")
            XView(customFlag: $customFlag)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        }
    }
}

struct UIKitBindingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UIKitBindingView()
    }
}

struct XView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = XUIView
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<XView>
    @Binding var customFlag: Bool
    
    init(customFlag: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._customFlag = customFlag
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> XUIView {
        Swift.print("XView: \(#function)")
        let v = XUIView(frame: .zero, customFlag: $customFlag)
        return v
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: XUIView, context: Context) {
        Swift.print("XView: \(#function)")
        // uiView.customFlag = $customFlag
        Swift.print("XView: \(#function): customFlag: \(customFlag) \n--\($customFlag)")
        uiView._update()
    }
}

class XUIView: UIView {
    weak var button: UIButton?
    var customFlag: Binding<Bool>
    
    init(frame: CGRect, customFlag: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.customFlag = customFlag
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Swift.print("XUIView: \(#function)")
        _configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.customFlag = Binding(get: { true }, set: { v, t in })
        super.init(coder: coder)
        Swift.print("XUIView: \(#function)")
        _configure()
    }
    
    deinit {
        Swift.print("XUIView: \(#function)")
    }
    
    func _update() {
        Swift.print("XUIView: \(#function): \(customFlag.wrappedValue)\n--\(customFlag)")
        button?.setTitle("BUTTON:" + (customFlag.wrappedValue ? "ON" : "OFF"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    private func _configure() {
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        let b = UIButton()
        button = b
        self.addSubview(b)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let cons = [
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.centerXAnchor),
            self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.centerYAnchor),
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(cons)
        b.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        b.addAction(UIAction(handler: { action in
            Swift.print("XUIView: \(#function): button action ***")
            self.customFlag.wrappedValue.toggle()
        }), for: .touchUpInside)
        _update()
    }
}
```

Console output after tapping the button:

```
XUIView: __preview___configure(): button action ***
XView: __preview__updateUIView(_:context:)
XView: __preview__updateUIView(_:context:): customFlag: true 
--Binding<Bool>(transaction: SwiftUI.Transaction(plist: []), location: SwiftUI.LocationBox<SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.Bool>.(unknown context at $10594f2e0).ScopedLocation>, _value: true)
XUIView: __preview___update(): false
--Binding<Bool>(transaction: SwiftUI.Transaction(plist: []), location: SwiftUI.LocationBox<SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.Bool>.(unknown context at $10594f2e0).ScopedLocation>, _value: false)
```

Comment: In `private func _configure()` have you tried using `button = UIButton()` and replacing all the `b` with `button`

Comment: Binding is a property wrapper per documentation. Literal use isn’t documentes. Also using Binding in a class isn’t appropriate either it requires a body. It should only be used in a SwiftUI view.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I think this should not influence things. As a result I would either have to `guard let button = button...` or live with optional `button` a lot.

Comment: @loremipsum So basically this would mean, that the `updateUIView` method would have to propagate all state updates and one could not use `Binding` to "help" with this, right?

Comment: Yes/No, update can be used to propagate updates from SwiftUI to UIKit. To go from UIKit to SwiftUI you need something else, completion handlers, shared source of truth, etc.

Comment: Binding only works in a SwiftUI when used as a wrapper in a DynamicProperty or View, there is a long explanation but in short it conforms to DynamicProperty and any updated values need a View.body to propagate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Textfield value to view controller through button click in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui)

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the hint for the other answer. It somewhat answers my question in that it provides a solution, but `Binding`'s behaviour is still a bit weird. I understand that this is a "proper" result of not being documented for a use like in my example. It still bothers me that the button toggles the wrappedValue of the very binding, which later behaves as if there was no toggle call. It looks like one just has to live with how it is and remember not to use it like that :-)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211411/problems-trying-to-use-environment-with-binding/76213700#76213700) is another answer that I wrote for someone else, it isn't specific to your question but it includes a lot of the "why".

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the other answer hint. If you add an answer to my question, I'll accept it. (I'll be happy, if you mentioned that "my" use of Binding is not intended by Apple.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Binding<Bool>` as a literal isn’t a documented used of `Binding`.

Binding should be used as an `@Binding` property wrapper.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

It is also important to note that Binding conforms to `DynamicProperty` therefore it should only be used in a `View` or a `struct` that also conforms to `DynamicProperty`.

> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

You can communicate from SwiftUI to UIKit using `updateUIView` and from UIKit to SwiftUI using completion handlers, a shared source of truth, a delegate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `_update()` of the XUIView (remove that method), make the update directly in the `updateUIView(_ uiView: XUIView, context: Context)`:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: XUIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.button?.setTitle("BUTTON:" + ($customFlag.wrappedValue ? "ON" : "OFF"), for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting about going from UIKit to SwiftUI when the button is tapped. Also when updating using update you need to guard against duplication.

Comment: @loremipsum what do you exactly you mean with "updating using update" ? I suggested to delete the _update() method and set the title directly from the updateUIView. I tested this code and the text got updated - showing on both elements (Text and XUIView) the correct ON/OFF value (which was not the case before).

Comment: updateUIView is what I meant.

Comment: According to the description, the issue was that the Text updated properly but the title of the UIButton's not. Setting it directly from the updateUIView fixes the behavior.

Comment: It bypasses the behavior not fix it. The Binding is still “outdated”

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update the `UIView` with the new binding value, e.g.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: XUIView, context: Context) {
    ...
    uiView.customFlag = _customFlag
    ...
}
```

Note it is a little bit lazy to just pass the binding along. It would be better to set your own closure. Binding is basically a pair of get and set closures, but your coordinator is only interested in a set closure, so could just create a didChangeCustomFlag and pass a closure that sets the representable's binding. See Fruta's PaymentButton.swift for an example of this pattern.

Comment: I noticed, that this makes the thing behave as I wanted, but I was wondering, why the Binding does not work as I expected it to work.

Comment: The reason is the representable is a struct that is being reinit many times but the UIView is an object that is created once. The point of the update method is to copy all of the representable structs values to the UIView (and the coordinator).

Comment: @AnnettSchwarze if it worked can you upvote please so others know to try this too

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the Binding type was used improperly, the BindingBool> in the XUIView was unable to see the changed value. You need to change the XUIView when initializing the custom flag you need to declare it as 'self.$_customFlag'.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> XUIView {
        Swift.print("XView: \(#function)")
        let v = XUIView(frame: .zero, customFlag: self.$customFlag)
        return v
}
```

also in the updateUIView function, you can remove the comment line for updating the binding variable.

```
uiView.customFlag = $customFlag
```