# Why is Binding with a @StateObject not updating?

Tags: swiftui

I pass a @State value from the `ContentView` to the `ChildView`. in the `Childview` i initialize a ViewModel as a @StateObject and pass the Binding to it. The value is binded to the TextField. When i enter a number in the TextField the `ContentView` gets updated, but the `ChildView` does not!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ContentView amount: \(amount)") // updates
            ChildView(amount: $amount)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    init(amount: Binding<Int>) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: MyViewModel(amount: amount))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", value: viewModel.amount, format: .number)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("ChildView amount: \(viewModel.amount.wrappedValue)") // not updating
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var amount: Binding<Int>

    init(amount: Binding<Int>) {
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this? `amount` in `MyViewModel` is always 0. When i initialize the `MyViewModel` as `@ObservedObject` it works as expected. But with `@StateObject` only `ContentView` gets updated.

Comment: The structure of your code doesn't make sense. Why would an `ObservableObject` ever have a `Binding`? This is definitely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You are right. But posting the whole thing is too big and complex. I'm just trying too understand SwiftUI basics here.

Comment: Since this is SwiftUI you shouldn't have view model objects since that's what the View struct is for.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create `viewModel` in `ContentView` and use that as *source of truth*. This avoids also the cumbersome `init` methods.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               Text("ContentView amount: \(viewModel.amount)")
               ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)
           }
       }
}
```

---

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", value: $viewModel.amount, format: .number)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("ChildView amount: \(viewModel.amount)")
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var amount = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Binding` as a literal isn't supported, `Binding` per the documentation is a `propertyWrapper` and should be used as `@Binding`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

`Binding` is a `DynamicProperty` which is

> An interface for a stored variable that updates an external property of a view.

> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

So these `DynamicProperty` are intrinsically tied to a `View`. They don't work anywhere else because there has to be a `body`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

An `ObservableObject` isn't a `View`/doesn't have a `body`.

For an `ObservableObject`to work there has to be a something (`@Published` or `@AppStorage`) that emits a value change via `objectWillChange`, an `ObservableObject` that synthesizes the emission and a `DynamicProperty` that invalidates the `View` (`@StateObject` to initialize, `@ObservedObject` to pass around and `@EnvironmentObject` to pass around further)

`Binding` doesn't "emit" therefore can't be synthesized and therefore does not tell one of the wrappers to reload the body.

I posted a longer version of this here it is more focused towards that question [Problems trying to use .environment with Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211411/problems-trying-to-use-environment-with-binding/76213700#76213700)