# How to show SwiftUI alerts based on conditions

Tags: swiftui

I have a `@Published` property in a view model and I want to present 2 different alerts based on some condition. For the alerts I'm trying to use the `.alert(titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, isPresented: Binding<Bool>, actions: () -> View)`

I don't want to use any deprecated modifiers. How to handle this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllSmall) {// Cannot assign to property: 'isAllSmall' is a get-only property
            //some buttons
        }
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllCap) {// Cannot assign to property: 'isAllCap' is a get-only property
            //some buttons
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public init() {}
    @Published var queryString: String = "some text"
    
    @Published var isAllSmall: Bool { queryString == queryString.lowercased() }// Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property
    @Published var isAllCap: Bool { queryString == queryString.uppercased() }// Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a single source of truth which in this case should be `queryString`.

Then instead of having `@Published` on your `Bool`s you would just make those a computed property.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConditionalAlertView: View {
    //StateObject is for initializing
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world! \(viewModel.queryString)")
            
            Button("make uppercased") {
                viewModel.isAllCap = true
            }.disabled(viewModel.isAllCap)
            Button("make lowercased") {
                viewModel.isAllSmall = true
            }.disabled(viewModel.isAllSmall)
        }
        .padding()
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllSmall) {
        }
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllCap) {
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public init() {}
    @Published var queryString: String = "some text"
    
    var isAllSmall: Bool {
        get {
            queryString == queryString.lowercased()
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                queryString = queryString.lowercased()
            } //False doesn't matter because the string could be in any other status.
        }
    }
    var isAllCap: Bool {
        get {
            queryString == queryString.uppercased()
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                queryString = queryString.uppercased()
            } //False doesn't matter because the string could be in any other status.
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ConditionalAlertView()
}
```

There are other way that would accomplish something similar and less convoluted way such as

```
func alert<E, A>(
    isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
    error: E?,
    @ViewBuilder actions: () -> A
) -> some View where E : LocalizedError, A : View
```

That can present an alert with any `errorDescription` you choose.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(ispresented:error:actions:)

The biggest flaw with this approach is that you can trigger the alert every time the `queryString` changes.

Comment: You added a setter to `isAllSmall`/`isAllCap` that is rather superficial. Sure, it might be convenient to uppercase/lowercase the query string just by setting them to true, but this is not relevant to the alerts. As far as the alert is concerned, you might as well have put an empty setter and there is no difference. And at that point, you could have just used `.constant` instead.

Comment: From a more philosophical perspective, there are multiple truths here - `queryString` and whether each alert is presented, so it is natural to have multiple sources of truth. Since the alert can be dismissed by the user, whether they are presented are not completely dependent on `queryString`.

Comment: @Sweeper noted… constant is a pet peeve for me. I don’t think it is acceptable outside of previews. As far as making the alert dependent on query string, that is exactly how the user had it in their sample. I wouldn’t use this approach at all. Also, the OP stated that is what the want.

Comment: @loremipsum How a computed property without any property wrappers becomes Binding<Bool>. I thought it would be just Bool.

Comment: Binding comes from DynamicProperty which in this case comes from StateObject/ObservedObject. Published doesn’t provide Binding it is just a piece of the puzzle. @arunsiva

Comment: @arunsiva see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211411/problems-trying-to-use-environment-with-binding/76213700#76213700) it is for a much more complex issue but it breaks all the pieces down. Look at Part 2.

Comment: @arunsiva if I answered your question do you mind clicking on the green checkmark and maybe upvoting?

Answer (score 1):

I found simply adding this Swift `Combine` observation to your `queryString` would be a nicer solution. Check this out.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .alert("Test All Small", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllSmall) {
            // your action
        }
        .alert("Test All Capital", isPresented: $viewModel.isAllCap) {
            // your action
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var queryString: String = "some text"
    @Published var isAllSmall: Bool = false
    @Published var isAllCap: Bool = false

    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $queryString.sink { queryString in
            self.isAllSmall = queryString == queryString.lowercased()
            self.isAllCap = queryString == queryString.uppercased()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have additional `@State`s in your view to represent whether the alerts are presented. You cannot directly use `isAllSmall` and `isAllCap` because it is *possible* for `isAllSmall` to be true but the alert is not presented. For example, this would be the case after the user dismisses the alert.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // IMO you shouldn't need a view model here - just make queryString a @State too
    // but if you insist, the view model should be a @StateObject not @ObservedObject
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    @State private var allSmallAlertPresented = false
    @State private var allCapAlertPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            TextField("", text: $viewModel.queryString).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
        .padding()
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $allSmallAlertPresented) {
            //some buttons
        }
        .alert("Test", isPresented: $allCapAlertPresented) {
            //some buttons
        }
        // I assume you want to try to present the alert whenever queryString changes
        .onChange(of: viewModel.queryString) {
            if viewModel.isAllSmall {
                allSmallAlertPresented = true
            } else if viewModel.isAllCap {
                allCapAlertPresented = true
            }
        }
        // if you want to present the alert only when isAllSmall/isAllCap changes,
        // .onChange(of: viewModel.isAllSmall) and .onChange(of: viewModel.isAllCap)
        // remember to check the new value it has changed to! Only show the alert when they change to true
        
        // do this in onAppear too, if you need to
        .onAppear {
            if viewModel.isAllSmall {
                allSmallAlertPresented = true
            } else if viewModel.isAllCap {
                allCapAlertPresented = true
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public init() {}
    @Published var queryString: String = "some text"
    
    var isAllSmall: Bool { queryString == queryString.lowercased() }
    var isAllCap: Bool { queryString == queryString.uppercased() }
}
```

This is not how you are *meant* to do it, but using `isAllCap`/`isAllSmall` as `constant` bindings also kind of works.

```
.alert("Test", isPresented: .constant(viewModel.isAllSmall)) {
    //some buttons
}
.alert("Test", isPresented: .constant(viewModel.isAllCap)) {
    //some buttons
}
```

The alerts only show up when `isAllSmall`/`isAllCap` changes, and I would consider this an "abuse" of bindings.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to create any intermediate state properties. Is it possible to use custom binding property in the ViewModel?